# How to Filter in the "Add Media Popup" to show only "unattached" Media

Tags: wp-admin, media-library

Any idea how to hack WP 3.8.x for this feature?

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Answer (score 0):

Can't deliver a working example but there is this relevant section in **wp-includes/js/media-views.js on Line 3173**:

```
media.view.AttachmentFilters.Uploaded = media.view.AttachmentFilters.extend({
    createFilters: function() {
        var type = this.model.get('type'),
            types = media.view.settings.mimeTypes,
            text;

        if ( types && type )
            text = types[ type ];

        this.filters = {
            all: {
                text:  text || l10n.allMediaItems,
                props: {
                    uploadedTo: null,
                    orderby: 'date',
                    order:   'DESC'
                },
                priority: 10
            },

            uploaded: {
                text:  l10n.uploadedToThisPost,
                props: {
                    uploadedTo: media.view.settings.post.id,
                    orderby: 'menuOrder',
                    order:   'ASC'
                },
                priority: 20
            }
        };
    }
});
```

One filter refers to `uploadedTo: null` and the other one to `uploadedTo: media.view.settings.post.id`. So this is equivalent to "All Attachments" and "attached to the current post".

When an attachment is unattached its `uploadedTo` value is 0. I just tried to create a new filter for that but it did not return any attachments at all (I *do* have unattached uploads in my db).

**Line 581 of wp-includes/js/media-models.js** shows how the filtering mechanism is constructed:

```
uploadedTo: function( attachment ) {
    var uploadedTo = this.props.get('uploadedTo');
        if ( _.isUndefined( uploadedTo ) )
            return true;

        return uploadedTo === attachment.get('uploadedTo');
    }
```

I had guessed that a zero value would pass _.isUndefined() but it does not. So I'm pretty much clueless here. But maybe this pushes you or somebody else into the direction. The media framework is still mostly undocumented.